# Capture Image From Camera using intent creates empty Image file

Tags: java, android, camera

I followed this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics .
I had some errors, but I resolved them and the app was working fine.
Once you took a picture, the picture would be saved in under this path :
`Android/data/<YourAppPackageName>/files/Pictures`.
**However, after last OS update I'm getting an empty image file with size 0 B!**

How can I solve this issue?

here is my github project : https://github.com/AlineJo/CameraGalleryImage.git

here is my code :

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cameragalleryimage">
    <!--Permission to write to storage-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--Inform google play that your app can take pictures-->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- File provider is a generic way to store image file across different Android SDK, And it enable us to get uri-->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.cameragalleryimage.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/img_file_path"></meta-data>
        </provider>


        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UploadImageFragment**

```
package com.example.cameragalleryimage.fragments;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.cameragalleryimage.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class UploadImageFragment extends Fragment implements ChooseDialogFragment.ChooseDialogInterface {


    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 200;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 300;
    private Context mContext;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private ImageView ivImg;

    private TextView tvProgress;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String mImagePath;

    public UploadImageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_image, container, false);

        ivImg = parentView.findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
        tvProgress = parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_progress);
        progressBar = parentView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        Button btnChoose = parentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose);
        Button btnUpload = parentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);

        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ChooseDialogFragment dialog = new ChooseDialogFragment();
                dialog.setChooseDialogListener(UploadImageFragment.this);
                dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), ChooseDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        });


        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mImageUri == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please take an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Image URI Found : " + mImageUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return parentView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onGalleryButtonClick() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setType("image/*"); // specify the type of data you expect
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // we need to get content from another act.
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose App"), PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraButtonClick() {
        if (isPermissionGranted()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            showRunTimePermission();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.d("capture_error", ex.toString());
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,
                        "com.example.cameragalleryimage.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);

                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {//img from camera
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                ivImg.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {// img from gallery
                try {
                    Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);//2
                    Bitmap selectedImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);//3}
                    mImageUri = imgUri;
                    ivImg.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unexpected Error Happened while selecting  picture!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);// mContext.getExternalCacheDir();
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


    private boolean isPermissionGranted() {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public void showRunTimePermission() {
        // Permission is not Granted !
        // we should Request the Permission!
        // put all permissions you need in this Screen into string array
        String[] permissionsArray = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        //here we requet the permission
        requestPermissions(permissionsArray, STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // user grants the Permission!
            // you can call the function to write/read to storage here!
            openCamera();

        } else {
            // user didn't grant the Permission we need
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Grant the Permission To use this Feature!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

**img_file_path.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="/" />
    <!--    Android/data/com.example.cameragalleryimage/files/Pictures-->
</paths>
```

Comment: "Once you took a picture, the picture would be saved in under this path : Android/data/<YourAppPackageName>/files/Pictures." -- since you do not have `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in this code, the camera app will not store a photo in that location.

Comment: @CommonsWare I believe you mean  

takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);

Comment: Correct. That does not appear in your code in the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare unfortunately, adding this code will crash the app!

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash. Also, here is a sample app (albeit a bit older) that demonstrates the use of `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera

Comment: @CommonsWare good new is the image is saved now. but, Intent data is null :(

Comment: Correct. You are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. There will be no `Bitmap` in the result `Intent`. Instead, the photo should be saved where you requested via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible to get the bitmap then?

Comment: If there is a file where you requested in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you can have your favorite image-loading library load it, or use it with `BitmapFactory`, or something.

Comment: `File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );` Look. That is the code that creates an empty image file. Nothing else.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know why the captured image via camera is not saved in Gallery? If you know please answer of my question [How can I capture a new image using the camera and after that store it in the external storage? +50 Bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71283338/how-can-i-capture-a-new-image-using-the-camera-and-after-that-store-it-in-the-ex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super thanks to @CommonsWare and @blackapps comments I was able to get uri and display the captured image

You can find the updated GitHub project here:  https://github.com/AlineJo/CameraGalleryImage.git

here is the code I changed :

```
package com.example.cameragalleryimage.fragments;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.cameragalleryimage.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class UploadImageFragment extends Fragment implements ChooseDialogFragment.ChooseDialogInterface {


    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 200;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 300;
    private Context mContext;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private ImageView ivImg;

    private TextView tvProgress;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String mImagePath;

    private File photoFile;

    public UploadImageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_image, container, false);

        ivImg = parentView.findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
        tvProgress = parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_progress);
        progressBar = parentView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        Button btnChoose = parentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose);
        Button btnUpload = parentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);

        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ChooseDialogFragment dialog = new ChooseDialogFragment();
                dialog.setChooseDialogListener(UploadImageFragment.this);
                dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), ChooseDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        });


        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mImageUri == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please take an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
               else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Image URI Found : " + mImageUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return parentView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onGalleryButtonClick() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setType("image/*"); // specify the type of data you expect
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // we need to get content from another act.
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose App"), PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraButtonClick() {
        if (isPermissionGranted()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            showRunTimePermission();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go

            photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createFileInstance();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.d("capture_error", ex.toString());
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,
                        "com.example.cameragalleryimage.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);


                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri); //this code was messing, However adding this code will make "Intent data" (in "onActivityResult") to be null
                Glide.with(mContext).load(mImageUri).into(ivImg);//solution ask glide to load the image using uri

                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {// img from gallery
                try {
                    Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);//2
                    Bitmap selectedImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);//3}
                    mImageUri = imgUri;
                    ivImg.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                if (photoFile.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "You took an image, but you canceled it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mImageUri = null;
                }

            }
        }


    }


    private File createFileInstance() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);// mContext.getExternalCacheDir();
        File image = new File(storageDir.toString()+"/"+imageFileName+".png");
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


    private boolean isPermissionGranted() {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public void showRunTimePermission() {
        // Permission is not Granted !
        // we should Request the Permission!
        // put all permissions you need in this Screen into string array
        String[] permissionsArray = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        //here we requet the permission
        requestPermissions(permissionsArray, STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // user grants the Permission!
            // you can call the function to write/read to storage here!
            openCamera();

        } else {
            // user didn't grant the Permission we need
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Grant the Permission To use this Feature!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );`. That still creates an empty image file. Try for yourself. Start yhe camea and then cancel. You are left with this empty file.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps , never consider this scenario.

i can add this code to onActivity result :

 


`else {
              if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE){
                if (photoFile.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "You took an image, but you canceled it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }`

Comment: That makes no sense as the user knows that already. Its much better not to create that file at fore hand but only construct a File object.

Comment: I understand , the thing i followed this toturial : https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics
i'm afraid that if i move file creation code it may not work.

Comment: That tutorial is wrong to create an empty file already. Just remove File.createTempFile() and replace with less code to construct that File object. You need a File instance. Not create a file already.

Comment: so i change the code to this

    ` photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createFileInstance();
           }`


    `private File createFileInstance() throws IOException {
        String imageFileName = "test";
        File storageDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);// mContext.getExternalCacheDir();
        File image = new File(storageDir.toString()+"/"+imageFileName+".png");
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }`

Comment: I updated my answer please check it out. @blackapps

Answer (score 0):

If you are updated to Android10. Then use below code snippet.

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
```

Comment: my minimum SDK is 21, this is can be used in SDK 29 and above