# How can I capture a new image using the camera and after that store it in the external storage?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-external-storage, android-storage

I'm trying to capture a new image using the camera and after that store it in the external storage.

I followed this tutorial [Save the full-size photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath) and this [Add the photo to a gallery](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskGallery) but after running the app, The camera starts and captured the image successfully, But when I go to the gallery, Can't find the image who captured via camera!

```
//I changed this from com.example.android.fileprovider to com.test.app.fileprovider
android:authorities="com.test.app.fileprovider"

//I changed this line Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile); to below code
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.test.app.fileprovider", photoFile);

//I added this permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

//I enabled storage permission read and write
//I tested the codes on API 24
//minSdkVersion 21
```

**Manifests**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.app">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

    <application>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.test.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String currentPhotoPath;
    int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.test.app.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

}
```

Additional Question: What is the difference between this tutorial [Save the full-size photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath) and this tutorial [Add the photo to a gallery](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskGallery)?

The best answer will take `+50 bounty` from this account if I reached 50 points, Otherwise, I'll give him the bounty from my other account after 2 days.

Comment: `The best answer will take +50 bounty from this account if I reached 50 points, Otherwise, I'll give him the bounty from my other account after 2 days.` Strange you removed that from the subject of your post. Was a good attention drawer ;-)

Comment: @blackapps Marcin Orlowski Modified the title of the question but the offer still stands and +50 Bounty will be for the answer who I select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file will not be scanned by the MediaStore and hence will not be visible in Gallery apps as Gallery apps mostly get their info from MediaStore.

`getExternalFilesDir()` is a location private for your app and the MediaStore respects that.

> > How can I capture a new image using the camera and after that store it in the external storage?

Wrong problem description.

Once the camera app took the picture the camera app will save the picture to the file indicated by the file provider. There is nothing to do more then.

So before starting the camera and even before using FileProvider you should have determined a suitable location for your file and builded a nice uri for that file.

You have at least two options.

Use MediaStore to get an uri for a file in public DCIM or Pictures directory.

Use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` with FileProvider to get an uri for a file in the same public directories.

Comment: I want after capture a new image using the camera store the image in external storage and make it visible to other apps

Comment: Could you leave an example about how to save the captured image inside a folder called TestApp and make sure that is public for other apps

Comment: FileProvider class used for what?

Comment: You are using an app private directory now. But you have to use a public directory to make it possible to let your pictures be shown by Gallery apps. I told you what you had to change. Gave you two possibilities. Further you seem to be able to use FileProvider. So i dont understand what you ask about file provider. Further you know that you have to let your file scanned. And although you do the scanning wrong in principle you now now what to do. Giving code examples goes too far as it does not belong to the question that is the subject of your post.

Comment: I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskGallery) to scan the captured image but you said It's wrong way

Comment: I saw your code here. That could be done better. It's irrelevant where you got your code from (i will not follow that link). The code just does not do what you want at the moment. But can easily be improved. The point is that you know that you should let  the file be scanned. (Not needed if you use MediaStore like in my answer).

Comment: I don't know what you will lose if you leave an example! It would be an excellent answer and more clear

Comment: You will not loose but win if you try my second suggestion. The changes to your actual code would be minimal. If you then would say: hey file is created but scanning does not work... I wonder why you did not already try..

Comment: I'm confused a little bit about what should I remove from the code and what to add or replace, I'm trying since a week ago to find the problem but without any result so for that I posted the question.

Comment: Anyway I'll try your suggestions and tell you what happen

Comment: `File.createTempFile` throws `IOException` -> `Permission denied`, I enabled storage permission

Comment: Please post your modified code. Updat your post.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty as I said after 24 hours

Comment: Not needed. You hardly have points yourself. Keep them.

Comment: I should wait 24 hours to give you the bounty

Comment: As this is no bountied question i wonder if you could give a bounty. But anyhow dont do that. Your question was also too elementary to deserve a bounty. Keep the points. This is an order! ;-)

Comment: But if I don't give the reward to anyone then the system will take it and will not back it to my account, So it is better for you to take it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are right. I did not think of that. Thanks.